# How to make ajax request across sub-domain of the same website

Tags: jquery, ajax, access-control

please i need help here!
am working with jquery, ajax and php,
i wrote a function (PHP_FOLDER) like this.

```
function PHP_FOLDER(evt){  return "www.mywebsite.com/path/to/php/files/";}
```

the purpose is to enable me to call the function + the php file during ajax request. something like this:

```
$.ajax({ url:PHP_FOLDER+'script.php',});
```

this works perfectly when my current url is `http://www.mywebsite.com`. but it does not work when am logged on to `http://mywebsite.com` (without the www.)

this is the error i get on my error console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://www.mywebsite.com/script.php`. Origin `http://mywebsite.com` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

please how can i fix this??

Comment: Why don't you use relative url ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoded URL you can read window.location and dynamically change the value of domain.

Answer (score 0):

Thank all.
@Michal Borek it worked.
i use window.location.origin. like this

```
function PHP_FOLDER(evt){ return window.location.origin+'/path/to/files/'; }
```